# OMNeT++ simulation stuck at initializing

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I was running my simulation in OMNeT++ 3 months ago, and now that I've tried to launch it, it says initializing and it's stuck. The only "error" I get is the java.lang.runtimeError which doesn't really say much. Even that error doesn't pop up, you need to bring it up by clicking inside the OMNeT IDE. I am using OMNeT++ 5.4.1, SUMO 0.32.0, and Veins 4.7.1.
Sumo was checked with the gui, and it runs normally. I don't know which java version needs to be installed..
Picture attached,
[Simulation stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9mPl.jpg)
Please if any1 could offer a solution?

Comment: Found out what the problem was.. There is a .qtenvrc file in C:/Users/<username>/ which had to be deleted before starting the simulation.

Answer (score 1):

The .metadata directory in your workspace contains a detailed log of the IDE. I would try to upgrade to OMNeT++ 5.6.2 though, to use a later version of the IDE (and Eclipse which the IDE is based on)